# What is the outermost class 2^Σ* referring to on the Extended Chomsky Hierarchy?

Tags: terminology, chomsky-hierarchy

After having searched a bit, it seems I can't find terminology or references for this outermost class, 2<sup>Σ*</sup> in blue -- see below. What is it describing?

[image]

Comment: It's the power set of all sentences over $\Sigma$. In other words, it is all possible languages built from the alphabet $\Sigma$, since a language is just a subset of $\Sigma^*$, and the power set describes all possible subsets of a set.

Comment: Several comments on the diagram. 1. A language is either "recognizable" or "not recognizable"; there should be no room outside of these two boxes. 2. Whether $\text{NP} \neq \text{P}$ is not known/proved. 3. Whether $\text{PSPACE}\neq\text{EXPTIME}$ is not known/proved.  4. Any given language can be included in a "Turing degree."

Comment: @JohnL. it seems to be missing caveats like "contained in" or `<=` or `?=`, rather than a distinct `=` or `≠`. I don't have a caption for this figure.

Comment: Good point. However, had I drawn the diagram, I would have drawn the boundary of a box differently, such as dotted lines, if the box does not mean strict containment by the area outside of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$2^{\Sigma^{*}}$ means [the powerset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set#Representing_subsets_as_functions) of the full language $\Sigma^{*}$. It means the set of all subsets of  $\Sigma^{*}$, including the empty set and $\Sigma^{*}$ itself, i.e., all possible languages with alphabet $\Sigma$.

Here is the simple understanding. When we want to describe a language $X$ with alphabet $\Sigma$, for each string $w$ in  $\Sigma^{*}$, there are $2$ choices, including $w$ in $X$ or excluding $w$ from $X$. All these choices are independent.